# Creating a Countdown Component in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, countdowntimer, buttonclick

Currently working on small project that involves building a pomodoro clock, but I'm stuck at the counter component. this is a tweaked portion of the code I've worked out below

```
import React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Timer = ({ sessions, breaks }) => {
    const [minutes, setMinutes] = useState(sessions);
    const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(0);
    const [onSession, setOnSession] = useState(true);

    const startCount = () => {
        let myInterval = setInterval(() => {
            if (seconds > 0) {
                setSeconds(seconds - 1);
            }
            if (seconds === 0) {
                if (minutes === 0) {
                    clearInterval(myInterval);
                    setOnSession(false);
                } else {
                    setMinutes(minutes - 1);
                    setSeconds(59);
                }
            }
        }, 1000);
        return () => {
            clearInterval(myInterval);
        };
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>{onSession ? "Session" : "Break"}</h2>

            {minutes === 0 && seconds === 0 ? null : (
                <h1>
                    {" "}
                    {minutes < 10 ? `0${minutes}` : minutes}:
                    {seconds < 10 ? `0${seconds}` : seconds}
                </h1>
            )}
            <button onClick={startCount}>Start</button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Timer;
```

The value of the minute state is gotten from the state(session) in the App component. Seconds is initially set to 0. Problem I'm facing is whenever i click the start button, depending on how its tweaked, the countdown starts to run but either glitches along the line or the *seconds* part just stops at whatever value the setSeconds is set to.

PS: The countdown in the code block runs perfectly and as expected when wrapped with/ called inside a useEffect.

Comment: Why not converting the time you run down to seconds and then just convert them in the view to minutes and seconds rather than having to deal with base 60 and all that

Comment: thanks. i'll try working on that and get back to you. sounds a lot better.